# SMLNJ want to remove "val it = () : unit" from every print statement execution

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am writing sml programs which run on SML/NJ and MLton (not interactive).  When I use print statements in the the sml file, SML/NJ always adds

```
val it = () : unit
```

to the output, which clutters up the output.  MLton does not do this.

Is there a way to remove this output?  I have tried CM_VERBOSE=false, which did not help.

Running SML/NJ v110.73.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without examples of the code that produces this, it is a bit hard to help, however it seems that your "issues" are somewhat related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186848/how-to-disable-smlnj-warnings).

In summary, remember to bind all result values to something, such that the `it` variable don't get assigned to the result:

```
val _ = print "fooo"
```

Comment: If it solved your question, the you might want to accept the solution, or state what you are missing.